# Add a pause on hover to carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I am trying to add a pause on hover to my carousel. I am relatively new to scripting, so I haven't been able to get the pause to work correctly. I am looking for some feedback on what I am doing wrong and any helpful suggestions. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="carouselContainer">
<div class="carouselTop">
    <div class="arrowLeft"><a href="#" id="left"><img src="img/left.png" style="position:absolute;"></a></div>
    <div class="imgWindow">
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="img/pic1"></a></div>
            <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="img/pic2"></a></div>
            <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="img/pic3"></a></div>
            <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="img/pic4></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowRight"><a href="#" id="right"><img src="img/right.png" style="position:absolute;"></a></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slideContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();

    var nextSlide = function() { 
        $(".slideContainer > div:first")
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo(".slideContainer");
    }

    var nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide,  3000);

    $(".arrowLeft").click(function() {
        clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);

        $(".slideContainer > div:first")
        .fadeOut(500);
        $(".slideContainer > div:last")
        .fadeIn(500)
        .prependTo(".slideContainer");

        nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000)
        setTimeout(nextSlideTimer, 3000)
    });

    $(".arrowRight").click(function() {
        clearInterval(nextSlideTimer);

        $(".slideContainer > div:first")
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo(".slideContainer");

        nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000)
        setTimeout(nextSlideTimer, 3000)
    });

    $('.slideContainer').hover(
function() {
    $(this).carousel('pause');
},
function() {
    $(this).carousel('cycle');
}
);
});
```

Comment: something like `.delay()`?

Comment: are using a custom carousel or a plugin or...? can you specify more what you are using as carousel?  depending on your solution, there may be built-in options we can set

Comment: this is a custom carousel. added the html code above.

Comment: I don't see any HTML code above (yet).

Comment: now it works. still getting the hang of this @Coby

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $('.slideContainer').hover(
      function() {
        nextSlideTimer = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);
      },
      function() {
        clearInterval( nextSliderTimer) ;
      }
);
```